# AES 256 Encryption support in Java 5

Tags: java, encryption

I have seen that AES 256 Encryption Decryption works on Java 6 and above.

How can i achieve the same thing in Java 5 (apart from policy files)

Comment: Java 5 was EOL over three years ago http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html, tell whoever wants AES 256 they need to upgrade the platform

Comment: Java 6 is about to be EOL and with Java 8's release this year, and EOL date for Java 7 will soon follow.

Comment: could you please answer me rather than pointing out these options. we have legacy applications. please

Comment: Personally I think you are rather rude yourself, a quick look in the official documentation would have given you the answer. When you are asking for high grade security while your platform does not get security updates, you and the other readers *should* be warned. Your customers too, probably.

Comment: So in summary: It does work in Java 5, you need policy files in Java 6 and Java 7 anyways so Java 5 is not special in that regard, and if you are supporting legacy applications then why would you be introducing AES 256? And to top it off there is really no practical benefit to using AES 256 in preference to AES 128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html) library has support all the way back to 1.4.  It includes AES256, and as long as you don't use it as JCE provider, I think you can use it without policy files.

That said, the default [Java 1.5 JCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#AppA) (Java Cryptography Extension) does include AES256.  As you noted in your question, you would need to deploy an unlimited policy file to actually use the 256-bit algorithm.  This is unavoidable, but shouldn't be that difficult.  The bouncycastle link above tells you how to do it.